# python pandas graphing from df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, graph

I have a dataframe and want to make a line graph of the data but am confused on how to do so. My graph will be "Line `A` `M` (males)" with `haps` `('G', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'C')` over time.

X axis is year, Y axis is amount of that `haps` per year, graphed using the numbers from `0`.

In each of the graphs there will be lines for the different haplotypes of that group, I am using one group to provide a simple example.

What should I be using to create the graphs, assuming there will be multiple `Lines` and `haps` in the actual dataset?

`df`

| Line | Sex | haps | 0 | generation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | M | ('G', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'C') | 25 | 2001 |
| A | M | ('G', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'C') | 25 | 2002 |
| A | M | ('G', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'C') | 5 | 2003 |
| A | M | ('G', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'C') | 9 | 2004 |
| A | M | ('G', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'C') | 15 | 2005 |
| A | M | ('G', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'C') | 27 | 2006 |

I have tried `sns.lineplot(data=clean, x='generation', y=0, hue='Line', marker='o')`
and I get one graph with all of the `Lines` but I want to seperate them out and not sure how to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a suggestion.

Sample dataframe (values etc. might be nonsense):

```
from random import randint

columns = ['Line', 'Sex', 'haps', '0', 'generation']
haps = [('G', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'C'), ('G', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'C')]
data = [
    [line, sex, hap, randint(5, 30), year]
    for line in ['A', 'B'] for sex in ['M', 'F']
    for hap in haps for year in range(2001, 2007)
]
```

Now you could do the following to show all in one plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df_plt = df.pivot(index='generation', columns=['Line', 'Sex', 'haps'], values='0')
df_plt.plot()
plt.show()
# plt.savefig('plot_all.png')
```

Result is something like:

[image: First plot]

Or in groups of `line`-`sex`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for (line, sex), sdf in df.groupby(['Line', 'Sex'], as_index=False):
    sdf_plt = sdf.pivot(index='generation', columns=['Sex', 'haps'], values='0')
    sdf_plt.plot(title=f'Line: {line} - Sex: {sex}')
    plt.show()
    # plt.savefig(f'plot_{line}_{sex}.png')
```

Result is several plots like:

[image: Second plot]

Is that what you are looking for?